# “In + VERBing” vs “When + VERBing”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage, subordinate-clauses

I think the following clauses are equivalent, and yet I guess there must be some nuances that make them different.

1. **In working with others**, try to work as a team.
2. **When working with others**, try to work as a team.

Can one use them interchangeably without any slight difference in meaning?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use your first sentence here. Though 'This can be very helpful in working with others' seems more idiomatic to my ear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a slight difference between the meanings of the two .

"In working with others..." means 'as part of the process of working with others'.

"When working with others..." means something that occurs at the same time as as working with others

So:

> In working with others I broaden my understanding of different approaches.

but

> When working with others I keep a daily log of who I have interacted with.

Comment: I don't recall seeing this explained so well before, very nice.